# How to make "open in new tab" count as a left mouse click in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, browser, mouseevent

I am trying to count the number of click/downloads of files.

The problem is that some people do right click and save as or open in new tab from the context menu .

Now, I can register left clicks that is not an issue and straight-forward.

But when it comes to the right click and I register it as a download it will be incorrect because the user could change his mind, or just click on inspect or some other option and didn't save or open in new tab etc.

How to distill the count only if open in new tab or save (target) as is clicked in the context menu?

Because right now, I can only count right clicks which includes users selecting "inspect code" or abandoning the action altogether without any download or showing the file/image in new tab etc.

EDIT:
Think about images and not files that, yes, can be served via a server script (PHP, Python) and left/right click wouldn't matter, just the URL request itself.
However, images are already shown and the links are exposed, so, the mouse clicks is the only think I have outside of Nginx logs - which I don't have access to for this project. And, no, I can't upgrade the hosting or get the access to Nginx etc.

EDIT2 :
If it's not possible with JS on the client, then let me know. Perhaps it really is impossible this way.

Comment: Seems like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - you should be able to count the number of downloads on the server. Trying to fiddle with all the ways users can reach a link from the frontend fails from the start. You already noted how right-clicking doesn't count. What if a user copies the link and pastes it? Or scrapes the page and accesses the resource that way, bypassing the UI? Or just doesn't have JS enabled? Gust do it on the backend where you have direct access to every request to the resource.

Comment: I would have to go to the Nginx level (parsing headers going out) or the Nginx logs. I want to avoid it because I don't have access to Nginx on this level on this project/hosting - and, no, I won't upgade my hosting for this project. PHP can't do anything about left/right clicks in the client. So, I am stuck with JS. I don't care about copy/paste, the same way I don't care about if somebody memorize what is on the picture or write the link on a paper. If the API available to JavaScript is unable to do it, OK. I will dismiss all right clicks altogether. I guess it's 10 - 20% of mouse clicks?

Comment: I don't care about people who don't have JS enabled. It's mostly Emacs/TUI guys or people I have no interest in aka no money. A normal Windows user doesn't have JS off in his browser. Not everybody is Xah Lee ;)

Comment: If it's not possible just via vanilla JS, that's OK. I just wanted to be sure because I am not a JS guru by any means - unlike many SO people who knows all the ins and outs of JS. That's why I asked.